# How to add html class dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bootstrap-4

I have a login page with the texbox to email and password and I use Bootstrap framework to css style. I would change the border color from grey to red of input textbox interesting when it is empty then the user click the button to login. I wrote the code but when I click the button to login the color don't change.

Bootstrap documentation of this event https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#server-side

**Into tag `script`**

```
     if(password == "") {
        function verifyError() {
          var element = document.getElementById("password");
          element.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
        }
      }

      if (email == "") {
        function verifyError() {
          var element = document.getElementById("email");
          element.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
        }
      }
```

**Into html body**

```
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
          <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button id="login" type="button" value="login" class="btn purple" onclick="verifyError()">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for it not doing anything is that you are just defining a function when the password/email are empty. You have to call functions that you define in order for them to execute the operations within them. However, I don't think you actually need the functions.

Try this:

```
 if(password == "") {
    var passElem = document.getElementById("password");
    passElem.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
  }

  if (email == "") {
    var emailElem = document.getElementById("email");
    emailElem.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
  }
```

Note: The assumption is that you are calling this code inside your click handler (which you also have called verifyErrors()). I assume you have retrieved the values of password and email in the method before the if statements

Comment: With respect, this might patch the code, but doesn't address many of the basic issues with writing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Color is not changing because you have not remove the class previously used on that specific div. Try removing the class then add new class to list.

Try this instead:

```
if(password == "") {
    function verifyError() {
      var element = document.getElementById("password");
      element.classList.remove("form-control")
      element.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
    }
  }

  if (email == "") {
    function verifyError() {
      var element = document.getElementById("email");
      element.classList.remove("form-control")
      element.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue overall is your use of JS. There's quite a few basic problems in your approach (there really is no one quick answer to the issue). The below code will be a good example of how to get you moving forward, but to be thorough, you really need to review :

- Scope (when and where variables need to be declared)
- How to use classList.add (when in doubt, read the docs).
- Basic functions (like "Array.forEach), there's no need to duplicate    the verify function (just use one and feed it a list of
  elements you    want to validate)
- How to check for a "falsy" value (== "") is problematic
- And so on.

I'd strongly recommend a thorough read of one of the dozens of "Beginning JavaScript" books (not just a skim but some real study), and "JavaScript, the Good Parts" as a valuable resource to getting your head around the path to correct use of Javascript. Be forewarned; if you were trying to use your code as-is in a test or as a sample, you might get some pretty harsh response.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .form-control {
      width: 300px;
     }
    .is-invalid {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
           // "elems" should be an array of the field names you want to validate, so you can do all of them at once.
           function verifyError( elems ) {
             elems.forEach ( x => { 
              var element = document.getElementById(x);
              element.classList = !element.value ? [ 'form-control is-invalid' ] : [ 'form-control' ];
             });
            }
       </script>

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
      <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="login" type="button" value="login" class="btn purple" onclick="verifyError( ['password', 'email'] )">Login</button>


    </body>
    </html>
```